# ViewPager2 - How to use registerOnPageChangeCallback to check view pager item position

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

How can I use ViewPager2's `registerOnPageChangeCallback` facility to check the position of the currently visible ViewPAger2 fragment? I know this will consists of an `if`/`when` statement but don't know the correct way to implememnt this.

```
mViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                if (mViewPager.currentPage) == 0 {
                // do something
                }
                else if (mViewPager.currentPage) == 1 {
                // do something
                }
                else {
                // do something
                }
                super.onPageSelected(position)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Use the passed `position` to know where you are:**

```
 mViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                if (position == 0) {
                // you are on the first page
                }
                else if (position == 1) {
                // you are on the second page
                }
                else if (position == 2){
                // you are on the third page
                }
                super.onPageSelected(position)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 5):

Do not forget to unregister your callback in `onDestroy` in order to avoid possible memory leaks.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mViewPager.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(this)
}
```

Comment: Could have just updated the accepted answer, also you must pass the callback into [ViewPager2.unregisteronpagechangecallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#unregisteronpagechangecallback)

Comment: Why? After `onDestroy` the Activity that holds the ViewPager2 is garbage collected anyway --> ViewPager is also garbage collected --> so is the callback